# Database design for webpage tracker

Tags: java, mysql, database

I want to design a page tracker database table, but I am facing few issues with it.

```
create table pageTracker(
 ID bigint(20) NOT NULL,
 TrackerID bigint(20) NOT NULL,
 SessionID varchar(100) NOT NULL,
 pageViews bigint,
 pageVisits bigint,
 primary key(ID)
);
```

If I update `pageviews` and `pageVisits` corresponding to specific `SessionID` I can not query `pageViews` and `pageVisits` within specific time interval.

```
create table pageTracker(
     ID bigint(20) NOT NULL,
     TrackerID bigint(20) NOT NULL,
     SessionID varchar(100) NOT NULL,
     pageViews bigint,
     pageVisits bigint,
     time TimeStamp,
     primary key(ID)
    );
```

But if I add extra column time, if I want to insert each `pageViews` and `pageVisits` as new entry for specific time it creates huge number of entry in the table.

Is there any efficient way to do it?

Answer (score 1):

I am assuming that you want to update `pageViews` and `pageVisits` everytime against a `SessionID`. In this case first insert will have say:

```
Session ID = 23R4E11, pageViews = 1, pageVisits = 1
```

Now if same user revisits same page, you will update existing row as:

```
Session ID = 23R4E11, pageViews = 2, pageVisits = 1
```

In this case to maintain all the updates, you can create one more table called as `pageTrackerHistory` and then write trigger which can insert entry in `pageTrackerHistory` table whenever update is made on `pageTracker` table.

By doing this your operational table `pageTracker` contains minimal rows and `pageTrackerHistory` table contains huge audit records.

Hope this will give you some direction. :-)

Comment: i have to query  based on hour/day/weekly and the query will be huge expensive for pageTrackerHistory Table.

Comment: You can extract details from your timestamp like -- (A) SELECT DAYOFMONTH('1998-02-03'); (B) SELECT DAYOFWEEK('1998-02-03'); -- You can fire expensive query on audit table so that operational table will remain as is without impacting performance.

Comment: your idea relieving pageTracker table from huge data entry. but when i query for daywise/weekly/month based tracker data i have to query history table and it will take much more time.is it able to do more efficient searching on history table?

Comment: You need to create index on the table column when data is huge and you want to query it efficiently.